# How do I add decimal expansions without a calculator

Tags: arithmetic

Really not sure how to go about the two questions here and I have not been able to find something similar like this online. Would appreciate anyones help on how to answer the two questions! Thank you in advance.

[image: This is the question:]

Comment: the question tells you to do it by converting the decimals to fractions -- did you try that?

Comment: yeah I got 64/99 + 94/99 but i`m not sure if thats correct.

Comment: You can check if 94/99 is the same as.94949494... with the help of your calculator

Answer (score 0):

When converting part **a)** to a fraction, you should get:
$$\frac{67}{99}+\frac{94}{99}$$
If you divide by $99$, the digits on the numerator should repeat in the decimal form if the numerator is less than $100$ for positive integers.

---

**Let me demonstrate why:**
$$\frac{67}{99}=\frac{67}{100}+\frac{67}{9900}=0.67+\frac{67}{9900}$$
We can continue this process:
$$\frac{67}{9900}=\frac{67}{10000}+\frac{67}{990000}=0.0067+\frac{67}{990000}$$
$$\frac{67}{990000}=\frac{67}{1000000}+\frac{67}{99000000}=0.000067+\frac{67}{99000000}$$
Repeating this process infinitely gives:
$$\frac{67}{99}=0.67+0.0067+0.000067\cdots=0.\dot{6}\dot{7}$$

---

So, try to convert the decimal forms you have into fractional form, and add the two fractions for part **a)** and multiply for part **b)**.

If you wish, you can comment the answers you get below and I could verify them.